# SSD reaches 100% active time at random, causing freezes

Tags: windows-10, ssd

Specs:

Motherboard: Gigabyte AX370 Gaming CF

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700

GPU: AMD Radeon RX Vega 64

OS: Windows 10, up to date

RAM: 16gb

Storage: C:Liteon L8H-256V2G-11 M.2 2280 256GB, D:Seagate ST3500630AS 500GB. E:ST1000DM003 1TB

I've been experiencing this on and off for the past couple years now and what usually happens is this. At random intervals, my SSD reaches 100% and causes my computer to freeze for about 10-20s. It's even worse when I'm playing something like warframe or apex legends because the freezes boot me out of the lobby I'm in. Here's some other details I've noticed:

- No apps show up as 100% disk usage in processes tab of task manager
- When the freezes occur, I get events 129 and 153 in event viewer and they say the following.

> Log Name:      System
> Source:        disk
> Date:          8/5/2020 7:04:08 PM
> Event ID:      153
> Task Category: None
> Level:         Warning
> Keywords:      Classic
> User:          N/A
> Computer:      DESKTOP-II5I2L5
> Description:
> The IO operation at logical block address 0x7104d0 for Disk 2 (PDO name: \Device\0000003d) was retried.
> Event Xml:
>
>
>
> 153
> 3
> 0
> 0x80000000000000
>
> 56920
> System
> DESKTOP-II5I2L5
>
>
>
> \Device\Harddisk2\DR2
> 0x7104d0
> 2
> \Device\0000003d
> 0F01040004002C0000000000990004800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000042A
>
> Log Name:      System
> Source:        storahci
> Date:          8/5/2020 7:09:54 PM
> Event ID:      129
> Task Category: None
> Level:         Warning
> Keywords:      Classic
> User:          N/A
> Computer:      DESKTOP-II5I2L5
> Description:
> Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.
> Event Xml:
>
>
>
> 129
> 3
> 0
> 0x80000000000000
>
> 56921
> System
> DESKTOP-II5I2L5
>
>
>
> \Device\RaidPort0
> 0F001800010000000000000081000480010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007000000810004800000000000000000

- In addition, errors 508, 510, and 533 occasionally appear as well. Can provide logs for them as needed

I know the answer lies in the event viewer errors, but I need help deciphering them so I can single out the culprit.

Comment: The SSD manufacturer that you mention appears less than reputable: the only references to them that I could find were via Amazon and Ebay. I would suggest you try contacting the manufacturer directly for a replacement, refund, or for assistance if there is contact information available.

Comment: Trying to understand your drives, is this __C:Liteon L8H-256V2G-11 M.2 2280 256GB__ running under RAID ? If so why? It looks as though you only have the one _Liteon_ as a solid state drive. @Vivid Kraig Liteon is a know company here in the U.S., it is from South Korea. If it is the other 2 as a RAID it may not be the SSD.

Comment: @vssher I don't know how to find if my SSD is running under RAID to be honest. But to update, I did find out my SSD is the disk 2 mentioned in event viewer.

Comment: Nvm on my last question, I think I might of figured it out. I checked in my bios settings and it's running in AHCI. Hopefully I got that right. I also tried tinkering with the power settings in the past from google search results, but sadly nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same issue with a recent new build.  I tried all the suggested software fixes I could find online and none of them made a difference.

This morning it was very bad, causing a long delay on reboot and happening very frequently.  I decided to try replacing the SATA cable for the drive and so far the issue seems to have been solved.

Use Disk Management to determine which of your drives is Disk 2 as that is the one indicated in to your event log and try a new SATA cable to it.